# IMAP IDLE is not returning any information despite new emails whilst running

Tags: python, imap

So I'm trying to setup a very simple imap IDLE script (Python 3.10). I've seen examples that all contain identical syntax and it compiles fine, however the mail server doesn't appear to be returning any information when a new email is received during IDLE.

I've tried using **IMAPClient** and **imap_tools**. Both of which have successfully accessed the inbox and displayed Subject, Dates etc.
None of them however are returning any data during IDLE for received emails

Is this what IDLE is meant to do? (I'm starting to question myself)
Perhaps there are settings I need to enable for it to work? (Microsoft Outlook)
Or is the syntax somehow incorrect?

**Edit:** Alternatively, if there are better libraries/modules to read new emails, download them and their attachments, please point me towards them.

For test data I'm sending emails to myself from 3 different accounts (*gmail.com, yahoo.com, outlook.com*) and none of them are working.

***NOTE:** I need to download attachments after I've got this working, and to my knowledge IMAPClient does not support this, so I need to use imap_tools or imaplib*

***General Vars***

```
# Naturally, these are not actual values used
HOST = 'imap.outlook.com'
USER = 'address@domain.com'
PASS = 'password'
```

***Using IMAPClient:***

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient

server = IMAPClient(HOST)
server.login(USER, PASS)
server.select_folder("INBOX")

# Start IDLE Mode
server.idle()
while True:
    try:
        responses = server.idle_check(timeout=30) # IDLE for 30 seconds
        print("Server sent:", responses if responses else "nothing")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
server.idle_done()
print("\nIDLE mode done")
server.logout()
```

***Using imap_tools: Example 1***

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

with MailBox(HOST).login(USER, PASS) as mailbox:

    mailbox.idle.start()
    responses = mailbox.idle.poll(timeout=60) # IDLE for 60 seconds
    mailbox.idle.stop()

    if responses:
        for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(seen=False)):
            print(msg.date, msg.subject)
    
    else:
        print('No new emails')
```

***Using imap_tools: Example 2***

```
import time, socket, imaplib, traceback
from imap_tools import A, MailBox, MailboxLoginError, MailboxLogoutError

done = False

while not done:
    connection_start_time = time.monotonic()
    connection_live_time = 0.0
    try:
        with MailBox('imap.outlook.com').login(USER, PASS, 'INBOX') as mailbox:
            print('@@ new connection', time.asctime())

            while connection_live_time < 29 * 60:
                try:
                    responses = mailbox.idle.wait(timeout=3 * 60)
                    print(time.asctime(), 'IDLE responses:', responses)

                    if responses:
                        for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(seen=False)):
                            print('->', msg.date, msg.subject)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print('~KeyboardInterrupt')
                    done = True
                    break
                connection_live_time = time.monotonic() - connection_start_time

    except (TimeoutError, ConnectionError, imaplib.IMAP4.abort, MailboxLoginError, MailboxLogoutError, socket.herror, socket.gaierror, socket.timeout) as e:
            
        print(f'## Error\n{e}\n{traceback.format_exc()}\nReconnecting in a minute. . .')
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Are you sure the server supports IDLE properly?

Comment: @tripleee To my knowledge it is, however I can only find very limited information/documentation on IMAP in general, nevermind IDLE specifically. I would be surprised if Outlook was not supported with IDLE, given it does support IMAP. EDIT: I recall seeing posts regarding people using IDLE for Outlook and mentioning issues popping up, but it was otherwise working for them. So again I'd assume it does support outlook

Comment: You seem to be confused. Outlook is a client. The IMAP server will indicate `IDLE` in its response to the `CAPABILITIES` command if it supports this extension. If it's a Microsoft product, it would not be unheard of for it to claim one thing but for another to actually be true, though.

Comment: See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9051.html for the current IMAP2rev4 spec.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe switch to another mail server will get everything works fine...
Outlook's Idle feature worked well for me until August 12, then it failed to trigger properly.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: @AndreyF My python script using imapclient worked fine with Outlook email for 2 years until August 12. The same script works fine with Gmail till now. I would be grateful if you could give some more useful suggestions.